# day diff with max date

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

```
category      last_updated      
abc           2019-05-20
abc           2020-06-14
abc           2017-04-26
def           2021-08-26
ghi           2020-08-25
```

There are many other columns as well, I am trying to get the difference in terms of days between max(last_updated) per category and overall last_updated date, like `datediff(day,max(last_updated) over (partition by category), max(last_updated))`, result:

```
category      last_updated      day_diff    
abc           2019-05-20        438
abc           2020-06-14        438 
abc           2017-04-26        438
def           2021-08-26        0
ghi           2020-08-25        1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (max(date) over () - max(date) over (partition by category) 
       ) as date_diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT category,
       last_updated,
       MAX(last_updated) OVER ()
       - MAX(last_updated) OVER (PARTITION BY category)
         AS days
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (category, last_updated) AS
SELECT 'abc', DATE '2019-05-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', DATE '2020-06-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', DATE '2017-04-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'def', DATE '2021-08-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ghi', DATE '2020-08-25' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CATEGORY | LAST_UPDATED | DAYS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | abc | 20-MAY-19 | 438 |
> | abc | 14-JUN-20 | 438 |
> | abc | 26-APR-17 | 438 |
> | def | 26-AUG-21 | 0 |
> | ghi | 25-AUG-20 | 366 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e44114e7ef8be7a6b4a56ece5f662e47)*